# SpaCy Install (extended) fails with pip install

Tags: python, installation, pip, spacy

In need of a python module that features a good POS tagger for the German language SpaCy was recommended to me.
On my Win10 64Bit with Python 3.4 I tried installing SpaCy as stated on its homepage, first preparing the virtualenv (installed partially, windows failed at source .env/bin/activate), then using pip install.
As this was not quite working, I cloned SpaCy from github via the git cmd and then continued in the windows console using `virtualenv .env && source .env/bin/activate` which again failed at "source".
After that `pip install -r requirements.txt` fails aswell.

I tried `pip install -U spacy` then which seemed to work fine (no error messages) but further commands for using SpaCy (installing a model for example), using `python -m spacy.en.download --force` all fail with `Error while finding spec for 'spacy.en.download' (<class 'ImportError'>: No module named 'spacy.attrs')`.

What did I do wrong? How can I ensure a smooth install of SpaCy? It's at least in the list when I try `pip list`.
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: The module has installed successfull here, output console + libraries http://pastebin.com/eGwsKc1V It does not missed any dependency?

Comment: Not sure if this is much help, but even though on the website it says it's compatible with 3.3+, I only got it working with 2.7.

Comment: I followed every step on SpaCys website so I can't seem to recognize any missing dependency :/

I doubt it just works with 2.7 but good to know.
Tend to think there has been anything missing when installing from source but upgrading Spacy doesn't fix this, either.

Answer (score 3):

I also met some problems while installing spacy using pip. I have two tips for you:

1. Try to `pip uninstall spacy` and reinstall it again.
2. using `conda install spacy` instead of `pip` which works for me fine.

Comment: "conda install spacy" worked for me instead of "conda install -c conda-forge spacy" as suggested in spacy website.

Answer (score 1):

Check the default version of pip you are using. I had the same problem.
My default pip version for installation was set to python3, so I tried

```
python3 -m spacy.en.download --force all
```

instead of

```
python -m spacy.en.download --force all
```

Answer (score 1):

Try remove it and install again:

```sh
pip uninstall spacy

pip install spacy
python -m spacy download en
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some incompatibilities between Anaconda and Spacy language download.
Here is a pending pull request to fix the issue
https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/pull/1792

Answer (score 0):

While trying to install spacy using conda, if you are getting `PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied` on windows 64, then you can directly type the below code in your virtual environment created in Anaconda prompt as described in the [conda-forge docs](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/spacy):

```
conda install -c conda-forge spacy
```